# Wrong app number of installs/current - google play statistics

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

My application on play store is not getting correct "current/total installs" on my developer console. 
I looked into google analytics and it is showing much higher number of total installs.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Comment: please check last updated date on your developer console. sometimes it takes 2-3 days to update your current installs and all data

Comment: @Ravi There is 7 to 9 days delay !

Comment: @hhyari How long did it eventually take?

Comment: Yes I am getting same issue, showing incorrect on Release Dashboard but showing expected number of installs inside MANAGE RELEASE